# Would an Athenian citizen, reduced elsewhere into slavery, remain a slave if brought back to Athens?

Tags: ancient-greece, slavery, athens

I understand that it was common at one time for debt defaulters in Athens to be driven into a form of slavery, or bonded servitude, and that Solon abolished this practice and freed all such bondsmen. But suppose an Athenian citizen were captured by pirates, say, while travelling abroad, and sold there as a slave, subsequently being brought by his owner back to Athens. Would he stay a slave? Would it depend on his former social status? Or the status (e.g. citizen vs. Metic) of his owner?

Comment: Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions. Please revise your question to document your preliminary research.

Comment: [Solon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solon)'s reforms ended the enslavement by Athenian citizens of other Athenian citizens. As for [Metics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metic), I'd be surprised if any would be daft enough to turn up in Athens with an Athenian as a slave. He would be at serious risk of be enslaved himself.

Comment: Note that in those days city-states (or any other state for that matter) was under no "international" obligation to respect any right of foreigners. It was all based on local customs, and standing of a master and the slave in the community. Therefore, as @LarsBosteen explained, showing up with the slave that someone could recognize as their brother, father, mother, sister ... could be dangerous for the master.

Comment: This is something I've tried to research myself. It's hard to find concrete examples of the situation, but I found a case of a Euxitheus whose father was enslaved in war. He later returned to Athens and his son, who became politically successful, was later attacked by his opponents, apparently with allegations of being the son of a slave. HIs defence of his lineage was subsequently recorded and seems to suggest that enslavement elsewhere did not change an Athenian's legal status, but may have incurred some some level of discrimination,